# How to check if a shape has the right link

Tags: c#, office-interop

I have a shape in a powerpoint presentation. I know it's ID/number and on which slide it is on. Is there a way to check if that shape has the right Hyperlink with c#? I want to do something like this:

```
string url = "http://stackoverflow.com/"

if (pptSlide.Shapes[4].Hyperlink == url) //This is the part that I am looking for.
{
  Console.WriteLine("Link is correct");
}
```

I have yet been unable to find any such function or method.

Comment: Please tell, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to check if a shape in a powerpoint presentation is linking to the right place.

Comment: You posted some code. As far as i can see, there's nothing wrong with it. So i really dont understand your issue

Comment: Now I get you.. the code I put in my OP does not work/exist. There is no `Shapes.Hyperlink`. Maye I should modify the code a bit to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
string url = "http://stackoverflow.com/";

if (pptSlide.Shapes[4].ActionSettings[PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink.Address == url) 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Link is correct");
}
```

The `ActionSettings` is your friend in this case. `PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick` might differ in your case